# Register presses on react-navigation cardOverlays (to dismiss modal)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen that loads as a modal with a transparent background (I made the BG for the sake of discussion).

I would like taps on the yellow part of the screen to be captured and call `navigation.goBack()` but it seems as though these taps are not being registered? are events not passed to the card overlay?  How can I accomplish this behaviour?

[image]

This is what the code looks like for this screen:

```
<LoggedInStack.Screen
        name={ADD_LINK_SCREEN}
        component={AddLinkScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
          cardOverlay: () => (
            <UNPressable
              style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', opacity: 0.5, flex: 1 }}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log('pressedCardOverlay');
                navigation.goBack();
              }}>
            </UNPressable>
          ),

          cardOverlayEnabled: true,
          cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS,
        })}
      />
```